# How can I hide the answers for a quiz in a front-end web application?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering

Let's consider making a quiz that runs in the browser. When creating such a quiz, you want to hide the answers to the quiz on the server side so that they wouldn't be accessible to the client using browser development tools.

For example, here's a [quiz application in Vue](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2018/01/22/building-a-quiz-with-vuejs) that is insecure because the JSON data containing the questions and answers is sent to the front end. I thought of using server-side rendering, but the answers are still sent to the front end.

What are some strategies I can use to hide sensitive data in a client-side JavaScript application? If JS can't keep the data secure, how can I approach performing validation of answers for a quiz app using a server?

Comment: Can you post your code attempt in the question itself as a [mcve]? Thank you!

Comment: It's a general question about SSR and using Vue.JS considering the options.

Comment: Then it's too broad, unfortunately. Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and take the [tour].

Comment: @ggorlen it's not too broad. It's a genuine question and has genuine answers.

Comment: Sorry, nothing personal! Folks who voted to close are not moderators, just other users, and there's a lot of content to sift, so if things tend to fit a certain pattern they can be misunderstood. I agree that the underlying question is not too off-topic on further reflection, but the framing of it struck me as very implementation-specific (vue tag, link to code that it seemed you wanted transferred to be server-oriented, etc). I voted to reopen, but I recommend editing to specifically be a bit more implementation-agnostic. The fundamental question is more clear after your update, thanks.

Comment: I did an edit for you, but if you don't like it, you can roll back using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57650769/revisions) or perform further edits to clarify your intent. Good luck on your app!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both HTML and JavaScript are public and **cannot** be hidden from the user. You can put in measures to make it more *difficult* for the user to view the answers written in JavaScript (such as [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) or [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))), but you still cannot prevent them from decompiling the code and reading it.

If, however, you were to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to fetch the data from the **server** (where it is either stored in a database or directly in a server-side variable), this would be completely hidden to the user, as the user cannot read server-side code (short of a security vulnerability).

Comment: Thanks very true, I'll have to learn more about AJAX and fetching data from the server. With Vue.js any direction to learn about this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I think that only safe solution is to send question parameters via http request (using axios or ajax) and to check if answer is correct on the server side. Or to submit whole quiz questions at once. In that case you would need to store your questions and answers in database. Only response from the server should be if answer is correct / incorrect. Basically everything that is on client side can be seen.

Comment: That's very true. I wonder if there is any server side api's out like this out there in the wild.

Comment: Also https://opentdb.com seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4deVCNJq3qc&t=3669s Learn Vue.js - Full Course for Beginners - 2019